# set condition on pause before in packer

Tags: packer

I have a script which reboots the instance. However the reboot happens only in certain cases. Is there a way I can put a condition on the `pause_before` n the provisioner that will run after the reboot. Since I would want it to pause only when reboot happened and not always.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Most of the times machines shutsdown sshd rather quick on reboot and `pause_before` can have a short duration and still work correctly.